# OAuth works with Authorization data in the header but not in the URL

Tags: oauth

I'm trying to use Google's OAuth in my system. I've successfully integrated Twitter and LinkedIn but i'm having hard times with Google.

I already have the consumer key, consumer secret and a valid access token. Using the G's OAuth playground I make a call to a protected resource (https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom). I've generated the token using this scope.

Using the authorization data in the HTTP header:

```
GET /mail/feed/atom HTTP/1.1
Host: mail.google.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="nounce", oauth_timestamp="1314727855", oauth_consumer_key="myconsumerkey", oauth_token="myvalidtoken", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="signature"
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
GData-Version: 2.0
```

The response I get from this is a valid HTTP call:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: S=gmail=yp_A23KtGOD9:gmproxy=PxCjSERnJWBbe; Path=/mail; Secure
Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2011 18:10:55 GMT
Expires: Tue, 30 Aug 2011 18:10:55 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 353
Server: GSE
<XML response here>
```

But, (and here comes the error), using the same access token but sending it in the URL as param (https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom?**oauth_token=myvalidtoken**):

```
GET /mail/feed/atom?oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=nonce&oauth_timestamp=1314729533&oauth_consumer_key=myconsumerkey&access_token=myvalidtoken&oauth_token=oauthtoken&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=signature HTTP/1.1
Host: mail.google.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
GData-Version: 2.0
```

I get an 401 error:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="New mail feed"
Content-Length: 147
Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2011 18:38:53 GMT
Expires: Tue, 30 Aug 2011 18:38:53 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
<HTML about my 401>
```

**EDIT**

I saw this example and I tried to use anonymous as consumer key and consumer secret. Now it works... but I need to show to the user the project's name declared in the Google's app registration page. I think i'm not using the correct consumer key and consumer secret.

Any clues on this will be appreciated. :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.5.3

In OAuth 1.0, the parameter name is oauth_token not access_token...

Comment: Great eye, I've incorrectly formatted the question. I'm using oauth_token in the URL param. I´m still getting the 
same error.

Comment: Your example now has both: access_token=myvalidtoken&oauth_token=oauthtoken